# Should NSNotificationCenter selector be with or without an NSNotification object

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

I'm doing some code cleanup and am wondering if there is an official or unofficial standard as to what option below should be preferable.

The basic issue is that I have to do some view change logic. This code should be called both in awakeFromNib and whenever a notification is received. To prevent writing the same code twice which option below is preferable.

```
// Option 1
- (void)receiveThemeChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)note {
        [self updateInterfaceWithTheme];
}

- (void)updateInterfaceWithTheme {
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
        [self updateInterfaceWithTheme];
}


// Option 2
- (void)receiveThemeChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)note {
        [self updateInterfaceWithTheme];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
        [self receiveThemeChangeNotification:nil];
}


// Option 3
// Registered as the selector for the notification directly
- (void)updateInterfaceWithTheme {
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
        [self updateInterfaceWithTheme];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty simple : If you want to send some data with notification ( e.g. `id`, `playerObject`, `name`, `anything`) use `NSNotification` as a parameter.

As far as I can see you don't need any parameters since you don't need anything from `NSNotification`.

`selector` is the same as you would add it to the button or anything else. If you need to know who is sender, or you need any kind of information inside that notification - use parameter. Otherwise you can skip it, and sometimes (like in your case where you call unnecessary "bridge" function) it is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

In the context that you do not use `note` for anything I'll go with Option 1. There is however one more option:

```
-(void)registerMethod
{
    __block __weak id observer;

    __typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

    observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Name"
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                                      if( nil != weakSelf )
                                                      {
                                                          [weakSelf updateInterfaceWithTheme];
                                                      }

                                                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer];

                                                  }];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self updateInterfaceWithTheme];
}

- (void)updateInterfaceWithTheme
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but wouldn't your solution remove the observer after the first call? I want to receive notifications for the lifetime of the observer.

Comment: Yep you are right, just store observer as property and call removeObserver in dealloc of the controller instead of the notification block and you are ready to go ;)